# stub fetch unit test react with enzyme and jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, sinon, enzyme

I am trying to stub an API call in react using enzyme and jest.

My React Component code looks like the following. This works perfectly.

```
async componentDidMount() {
    try {
      const res = await fetch(FETCH_ENDPOINT)
        if(res.ok) {
          const data = await res.json()
          this.setState({
            players: data.players,
            error: false
          });
        } else {
          throw new Error('Something went wrong');
        }
    } catch (error) {
      this.setState({
        error: true,
      })
    }
  }
```

I am trying to mock the response and test the success and failures of the api call. My test code looks like this, and it never updates `this.state.players` with the stubbed response from the  api. I feel I am making a simple mistake. Can anyone see what is wrong with the code below? It is just showing as length is 0, and not 2 for this line

Perhaps it is something to do with there being 2 promises in my componentDidMount api call, but I only have one in my spec file?

`expect(renderedComponent.state('players').length).toEqual(2)`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import App from './App';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme'

const result = {
    'players': [
      {
        'firstname': 'Robbie',
        'lastname': 'Keane',
      },
      {
        'firstname': 'Alan',
        'lastname': 'Shearer',
      }
    ]
  }

describe('App', () => {
  describe('componentDidMount', () => {
    it('sets the state componentDidMount', async () => {
      window.fetch = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
        status: 200,
        ok: true,
        json: () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          resolve({
            result: {
             'players': [
               { 'firstname': 'Robbie', 'lastname': 'Keane' },
               { 'firstname': 'Alan', 'lastname': 'Shearer' }
            ]
          })
        })
      }))

      const renderedComponent = await shallow(<App />)
      await renderedComponent.update()
      expect(renderedComponent.state('players').length).toEqual(2)
    })
  })
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you mentioned, you need one more Promise in your test file. Also, you should remove `result` property from your json object. Here is a working test code:

```
window.fetch = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve({
            status: 200,
            ok: true,
            json: () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                resolve({
                    'players': [
                        { 'firstname': 'Robbie', 'lastname': 'Keane' },
                        { 'firstname': 'Alan', 'lastname': 'Shearer' }
                    ]
                });
            })
        });
    });
})
```

Test Component:

```
import React from 'react';

const TEST = "test";

class Test extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        players: [],
        error: false,
    };
  }
  async componentDidMount() {
    try {
      const res = await fetch(TEST)
      if(res.ok) {
        const data = await res.json()
        this.setState({
          players: data.players,
          error: false,
        });
      } else {
        throw new Error('Something went wrong');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      this.setState({
        error: true,
      });
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (<div>Hello world</div>);
  }
}

export default Test;
```

Comment: thanks for this. Unfortunately it doesn't appear to work - the length is still equal to `0` for some reason. Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: @peterflanagan I just added Test component I used to test this. It returns the length of two. If this does not work for you, could you show me your full component code?